# Variables for Button onClick not passing from Code.gs to JavaScript.html

Tags: javascript, html, variables, google-apps-script, button

i have a simple WebApp.

I wrote script in another file ( not directly in Index.html)

I set onClick attribute to **ButtonA** from **Index.html** successfully.

and tried to set another onClick attribute to **ButtonB** from **JavaScript.html** file . But it's not working :(

What went wrong or how to achieve this..?

**[WebApp Link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxNpbe-iQ0zadcjeTjiDbcBsJC_ILLN9vOuNXxjHKMiOfu9QumVhCnOij-f0cfxXQQ/exec)**

**[App Script Link](https://script.google.com/d/1y9SIC1X-h0LfJd5Js0D1EtiadYOW8zTzNUrM99IC3_S4ppoiSAKTEkpW/edit?usp=sharing)**

**Below is the Code.gs file**

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index.html') ;
  var TodaysUrl = "https://google.com" ;
  template.TodaysUrl = TodaysUrl;
  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent() ;
}
```

**Below is the Index.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

    <style>
      .button {
        display : block ;
        text-align : center ;
        margin : 25px auto ;
        padding : 10px
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
      
    <button class="button" id="btn-a" >ButtonA Link from Index.html</button>

    <button class="button" id="btn-b" >ButtonB Link from JavaScript.html</button>

    <script>

      document.getElementById("btn-a").onclick = function () { window.open("<?= TodaysUrl ?>" )} ;

    </script>  

    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Below is the JavaScript.html file**

```
<script>

      document.getElementById("btn-b").onclick = function () { window.open("<?= TodaysUrl ?>" )} ;

</script>
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Hello, the script inside the JavaScript.html file should place inside the Index.html file. Then it will work as you expect.

Comment: Something is parsing index.html, and converting `<?= TodaysUrl ?>` into a url.  That thing is not parsing JavaScript.html.

Comment: Hi @James , then how to achieve this. I modified my code as TheWized said.. pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second button is not working because loaded in second time, and is not rendered by the "evaluate" function.

doGet > evaluate (define btnA) > includes JS file (which contains btnB, so won't render)

My suggestion would be to initialize your buttons with a custom function called after the DOM is loaded. Here an example with 2 differents URLs

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index.html') ;
  // var TodaysUrl = "https://google.com" ;
  // template.TodaysUrl = TodaysUrl;
  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent() ;
}

function initialize() {

  var obj = {};

  obj.url_a = "http://google.com";
  obj.url_b = "http://amazon.com";

  return obj;

}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

    <style>
      .button {
        display : block ;
        text-align : center ;
        margin : 25px auto ;
        padding : 10px
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
      
    <button class="button" id="btn-a" >ButtonA</button>
    <button class="button" id="btn-b" >ButtonB</button>

    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript.html

```
<script>

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(return_initialize).initialize();
  });

  function return_initialize(obj) {
    document.getElementById("btn-a").onclick = function () { window.open(obj.url_a)} ;
    document.getElementById("btn-b").onclick = function () { window.open(obj.url_b)} ;
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `TodaysUrl` to the template.

```
function doGet() {
  var TodaysUrl = "https://google.com" ;
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index') ;
  template.TodaysUrl = TodaysUrl;
  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

Include your script in the body of the html rather than from another file.

Comment: Hi @TheWizEd , I modified my code as you said, but still not getting that variable. Any Idea..?

Comment: Sorry I had a slight typo.  change `template.TodaysUrl = TodaysUlr;` to `template.TodaysUrl = TodaysUrl;`  It works for me.

Comment: still not working and this time I got **google drive error on ButtonB** Pls check webApp and you have also access to App Script file , so pls modify code according to..

Comment: I've added another suggested edit.

Comment: I have modified according to your above suggested edit. but it still not working. pls check WebApp [link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxNpbe-iQ0zadcjeTjiDbcBsJC_ILLN9vOuNXxjHKMiOfu9QumVhCnOij-f0cfxXQQ/exec)

Comment: Final suggestion.

Comment: I wondered that, why the same code worked for you and not for me. Anyway thanks for your time.